# How to query two meta fields and display results between them

Tags: search, query, post-meta

I am making a search form that searches for posts within two meta box values and display results between them.

I have this set

```
$prefix = 'ghes_'; // start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
add_filter( 'ghes_meta_boxes', 'ghes_sample_metaboxes' );
function ghes_sample_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    global $prefix;
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'event_meta',
        'title' => 'Event Metabox',
        'pages' => array('event'), // post type
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
        'fields' => array(

        array(
                'name' => 'Event Start Date',
                'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
                'id' => $prefix . 'event_start_timestamp',
                'type' => 'text_date_timestamp'
            ),                  
            array(
                'name' => 'Event End Date',
                'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
                'id' => $prefix . 'event_end_timestamp',
                'type' => 'text_date_timestamp'
            )
```

How will the query look like if I want to search for posts between the "Event Start Date" and the "Event End Date".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) variable like so:

```
$start = time(); //Now
$end= strtotime('+1 month'); //1 month ahead

query_posts(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('key' => $prefix.'event_start_timestamp', 'value' => $start, 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC'),
        array('key' => $prefix.'event_end_timestamp', 'value' => $end, 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC')
    )
);
```

Comment: Okay, I have this as my search form (custom-search.php): http://pastebin.com/vBzzmG83 and this is what I have for my search results page (search.php):http://pastebin.com/1Hv4s2qM When I perform a search, I get the "Nothing found" message even though I have posts with events happening between the dates I select. Maybe I am missing something here. The start and End dates of the events are saved as timestamps with the date format mm/dd/yyyy. I also tried pointing the form action like this `<form action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/search.php" method="GET">` and I hit a 404. Clues?

Comment: if the timestamp is saved in the db like mm/dd/yyyy change `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` to `'type' => 'DATE'`